# rename column name of spark data frame based on csv

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rename, apache-spark-sql

I've trouble renaming the header of a dataframe based on a csv.

I got the following data frame: df1:

```
Att1   Att2     Att3   
23      m        0      
22      m        1      
42      f        0   
32      f        0    
45      m        1
```

Now I  want to change the column names (first row) based on a csv file, which looks like this:

```
Att1,age
Att2,gender      
Att3,employed 
...,...    
Att99,colnameY     
Att100,colnameZ
```

As a result I expect a data frame, witch looks like this:

```
age   gender    employed   
23      m        0      
22      m        1      
42      f        0   
32      f        0    
45      m        1
```

any ideas?
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import scala.io.Source.fromFile

// read in the names map from old names to new names
val map = fromFile("names.csv").getLines.map(line => {
    val fields = line.split(",")
    (fields(0), fields(1)) 
}).toMap
// map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(Att1 -> age, Att2 -> gender, Att3 -> employed)

// rename columns using withColumnRenamed
df1.columns.foldLeft(df1){ 
    case (df, col) => df.withColumnRenamed(col, map.getOrElse(col, col)) 
}.show
+---+------+--------+
|age|gender|employed|
+---+------+--------+
| 23|     m|       0|
| 22|     m|       1|
| 42|     f|       0|  
| 32|     f|       0|
| 45|     m|       1|
+---+------+--------+
```